# onPressed is working is Debug/Profile/Release mode but not working in Release apk (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter

onPressed is working is Debug/Profile/Release mode but not working in Release apk.

What's the problem?
I cant' understand.

**Here is my code:**

```
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Progresshud.showWithStatus('Please wait...');
                  await _signUpOperation();
                } else {
                  wToast('Try again');
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                "Sign Up",
                style: FontStyleTheme().textBoldBlack(18),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Are these values ```_formKey.currentState``` not null ?

Comment: I don't know. But it works perfectly in debug/profile/release mode. But when I upload it to play store then it is not working.

Comment: Even if the `_formKey.currentState` is null, then it should show me a toast `Try again`. But it is not showing anything.

Comment: no it won't show the "else" it will throw an error and it will stop the execution.

Comment: So, why it works perfectly in debug mode?